# Trying to pass a sf::Image has a parameter for a class

Tags: c++, sfml

So, im trying to create a pacman game in SFML, i created a class named fant for my ghosts, 
im trying to pass a sf::Image has a parameter in my class, but it seems that I got a variable without a value, cause it load a blank image, but it has the same size (18x18 pixels) of the image im trying to load.

My class is

```
class fant {
public:
    void SetX(int i);
    int GetX();
    void SetY(int i);
    int GetY();
    void SetDX(int i);
    int GetDX();
    void SetDY(int i);
    int GetDY();
    void Sprite(sf::Sprite i);
    sf::Sprite GetSprite();
    void Image(sf::Image i);
protected:
    int posx,posy,dirx,diry;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
};

void fant::SetX(int i) { posx=i; sprite.SetX(posx); }
void fant::SetY(int i) { posy=i; sprite.SetY(posy); }
void fant::SetDX(int i) { dirx=i; }
void fant::SetDY(int i) { diry=i; }
void fant::Sprite(sf::Sprite i) { sprite=i; }
void fant::Image(sf::Image i) { sprite.SetImage(i); }
sf::Sprite fant::GetSprite() { return sprite; }
int fant::GetX() { return posx; }
int fant::GetY() { return posy; }
int fant::GetDX() { return dirx; }
int fant::GetDY() { return diry; }
```

and thats a function that create a new object

```
void addf() {
    fa.push_back(fant());
    int t=fa.size()-1;
    fa[t].SetX(684); fa[t].SetY(18);
    fa[t].Image(f1);
    fa[t].SetDX(6);
    fa[t].SetDY(0);
}
```

If i use

```
void fant::Image(sf::Image i) { sprite.SetImage(f1); }
```

it sets the "f1" image. (a global sf::Image)

Comment: oh, im sorry, I dont even know about this, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class fant {
public:

sf::Sprite GetSprite()
{
   return sprite;
}
void LoadImage(std::string path);
protected:
int posx,posy,dirx,diry;
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Image image;
};
```

and

```
void fant::LoadImage(std::string path)
{
   image.LoadFromFile(path.c_str());
   sprite.SetImage(image);
}
```